# How to break legend into multiple groups as per categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have regions as categorical variable and multiple countries under each region. If I plot multiple line chart for each region using facet_wrap I can see a plot per region but the legend is quite obscure as its not organised as per Regions. How can I  break the legends for each plot in `facet_wrap` showing only the countries within that group.

[image: Region wise migration pattern]

2. I tried to manually colour the countries to make more sense (as by default same colours are repeated but didn't help)

Below is the code I tried for problem 2 but it didn't help.

```
ggplot(data = temp_tidy, aes(x= year,y= population)) + 
   geom_point()+geom_line(aes(group=`Country of birth`)) facet_grid(Major_Region_New~. )+
   scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue","green","brown","yellow","pink","seagreen1",
                                 "gold1","sienna2","tomato","plum4","purple2"))
```

Actual plot should be 4 legends with 3 countries under each.

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Don't think you can make separate legends per facet, you'd probably be better off using `gridExtra::grid.arrange` or `cowplot::plot_grid`

Comment: I have two suggestions. 1. Add ```aes(colour=`Country of birth`)```, put inside one of your two existing `aes()` calls, either one will work. 2. Make your values a named vector to control which colour goes with which country: `values = c("Greece"="blue", "Malaysia"="sienna2", "Sri Lanka"="gold1")` etc..